# ImageMagick: How to extract tiles in a grid from a single PNG?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I know questions like this get asked a lot, but I haven't been able to find an answer to my specific use-case.

I frequently have to extract rectangular tile images that are laid out in a grid in a single PNG. The image contains a grid of M x N tiles. The upper-left corner of the upper-left tile in the grid is at offset (X, Y) in pixels. Each tile is WxH pixels in size. In addition, each tile in a row is DX pixels from upper-left corner to upper-left corner (so that DX >= W), and each column is DY pixels below the one above it (DY >= H).

In this picture, M=3 and N=2
[image]

Give all these variables, could someone please tell me what command to use to extract the six tiles into their own PNG files?  I'm assuming it's using the 'convert' command.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Linux, specifically Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple crop command in Imagemagick that will do the offset tile cropping. But you can do that with a combination of 3 crop commands.

- Crop the larger area that you want from the image
- Tile crop with no skip
- Crop each tile to remove the skip area

Input:

[image]

Here I make an animation simply for demonstration. Use PNG output or JPG output for separate tiles.

```
convert -delay 50 lena.png \
-crop 200x200+20+20 +repage \
-crop 100x100 +repage \
-crop 90x90+0+0 +repage \
-loop 0 lena_crop.gif
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't allow for a variable number of rows and columns.

Comment: It does based upon the first two crops. How big the overall area will be and how big the crop regions you assign to be cropped as tiles. The -crop 100x100 without the +X+Y will tile crop. Or you can use -crop MxN@ to specify rows and columns. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal

Comment: Alternately, write a script loop to crop each tile that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

COLS=8
ROWS=4
WIDTH=263
HEIGHT=500
XOFF=154
YOFF=176
DX=267
DY=523
IMAGE=image

mkdir -p ${IMAGE}
for M in `seq 0 $(($COLS - 1))`
do
    for N in `seq 0 $(($ROWS - 1))`
    do
        X=$(($XOFF + $M * $DX))
        Y=$(($YOFF + $N * $DY))
        convert ${IMAGE}.png[${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}+${X}+${Y}] ${IMAGE}/${IMAGE}-${M}-${N}.png
    done
done
```

I'm not sure how elegant this is.